# Как закруглить углы у UIButton? Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, mobile-development

Как закруглить углы у UIButton?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

либо создать его с закругленными углами

```
let button = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
```

либо задать радиус угла

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = 3
```

если задаете радиус, можно еще добавить цвет и ширину окантовки

```
button.layer.borderWidth = 3
button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
```

Comment: Очень полезный ответ. Спасибо!

Comment: Не подскажите как мне присваивать "определённый цвет". То есть есть у меня цвет в виде sRGB IEC61966-2.1. Как его присвоить?

Comment: `let color = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 1, alpha: 1)`

Comment: А как присвоить цвет из палитры (точнее, который я там сам задам)?

Comment: я в комментарии выше написал как задать любой цвет

Comment: Там диапозоны от 0-1. А в RGB от 0 до 255...

Comment: делите нужное вам значение на 255 и все у вас получится

Comment: Спасибо, получилось!

Comment: Вообще, можно было и самому догадаться.

Answer (score 0):

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = buttonn.frame.size.height / 2
```

Универсальное закругление - не хардкодим cornerRadius, кнопка всегда будет овальной (независимо от размеров кнопки)

Comment: А как передать цвет, который я в палитре задам?